# The getter 'uid' was called on null.Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

My App flow is like that:

Wrapper->Authenticate->Login

But when I run the app it gives me red screen and this exception:

```
    The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Wrapper(dirty, dependencies: [InheritedProvider<User>], state: _WrapperState#fd39b):
The getter 'uid' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: uid
```

I used to run it before and it was working good but I do not why now it show this exception:

[image]
Here is main:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<User>.value(
      value: AuthService().user,
        child: MaterialApp(
          title: 'Sayarty',
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.green,
            visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
          ),
          home: Wrapper(),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

And here is the Wrapper class:

```
    class Wrapper extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WrapperState createState() => _WrapperState();
}

class _WrapperState extends State<Wrapper> {
  int _currentTab = 1;

  final _page = [
    Search(),
    Home(),
    Account(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);
    print(user.uid);

    if (user == null) {
      return Authenticate();
    } else {
      return
//        Home();
       }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probably because now you added  `print(user.uid);` before testing `if user is == null`

Put it inside the else:

```
//print(user.uid);

if (user == null) {
  return Authenticate();
} else {
  print(user.uid);
  return
    Home();
}
```

Comment: Yes you are right, I deleted it and it worked.. Thank you